# Receive notifications of newly pushed children

Tags: firebase

I'm `.push()` ing into a firebase reference.

I want a listener to be able to come online, and then be notified only of newly `.push()` ed children.

So if the node already contains 5 children and client comes and wishes to be notified of new children, and 2 are pushed, then the client should only receive 2 notifications.

Right now with `.on('child_added',function...)` when coming online, the client receives not only new messages, but also all the old messages.  It's that second part I want to avoid.

I have also tried using `.startAt().limit(1)...`, but this doesn't seem to behave as desired either.  I am not sure what exactly it is doing with that, but certainly not what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startAt() returns the oldest (first) records, where endAt() returs the last (newest) records, assuming you've used push() to store them.

So this would give you the newest entries:

```
 ref.endAt().limit(1)
```

Keep in mind that the first record you receive will be previously existing, so it should be discarded in the use case that only data added after a user comes online is of value.

Comment: Kato, this answer is nearly spot-on.  The only discrepancy I'm seeing is that I have no need to discard the first one.  What you say makes sense (based on my understanding), but it's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: Oh, and thanks a lot.  I definitely had the order confused startAt vs. endAt