# Receiving notifications of child_added from that moment on

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am using Firebase both on the Browser client-side and on the server side NodeJS in order to make the site SEO friendly. And so, I'm rendering a list of items on the server side, and then listening to new updates on the client side.

I was not able to find a proper chaining for `on('child_added')` that will start listening to child_added notification from beginning a specific ID.

With endAt() or startAt(), these functions are [endpoint inclusive](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/query/endat.html), and so they return the last child as well.

Some other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114134/receive-notifications-of-newly-pushed-children) seem to indicate using `endAt().limit(1)` but this seems flawed, as there could be multiple child_added in between the gap. Also `endAt()` is inclusive and so the `endAt().limit(1)` still returns the last added child.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `once('value')`, then start the `.on('child_added')` listener in the `once()` callback, and compare the names of new children with those read initially in the `once()` call.

This is a little ugly though, and requires keeping a bunch of children names in memory. If you describe your use case in a little more detail, it might help people think of a better solution. How is your site designed such that you need to load only future additions, and can't throw out the query endpoints?

Comment: This requires to load all children into the local memory and as you mentioned doing some key comparison. There should be some clean way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could `push()` your own dummy data, then `startAt(null, the-name-of-the-dummy).on('child_added')`, and throw out the first result.