# How to distinguish old items and new ones in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code:

```
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 var database = firebase.database();
 var messages = database.ref('messages');
 messages.limitToLast(100).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
     var data = snapshot.val();
     if (data.random != random_value) {
         show(data.message);
     }
 });
```

and it get executed when new message is added as well on init. How can I distinguish between new message and old messages?

Comment: Knowing what defines "old" and "new" to you is the key to coming up with a solution. Here are a few good previous discussions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18270995), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19114134), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27693310), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12851236).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, I've mark this one as duplicate of the first one, which solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

On `child_added` it will always return *all* messages. On the first run it will return all those that already are in your database and after that it will just trigger when something is added that was not there before.

So if you just want *new* messages, you simply have to mark them as read in your database and go on from there.